# Is there a way to perform an action every time an object changes state?

Tags: c#

I have an object that gets passed to an interface, I would like for the concrete sitting behind that interface to perform some action every time one of the object's members changes state. In other words, I have some object that contains an integer. When the value of that integer changes, I would like for my concrete class sitting behind that interface to do some work.

Now, I could probably do something like this by having a thread that's sitting in the `wait` state and performs the action once some `pulse` is done using a `monitor`. But, I was wondering if the C# language had the inherent support for such a thing. Such that, when the object's member *changes state* the action will automatically be performed. I know that this may not be possible, and if there is an alternative solution I would like to hear that. Or, does the thread thing sound like a good idea?

Comment: Where do you want to "perform some action"? Is that from the consuming object (that object that receives the instance?) If so, can you just implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your interface and respond accordingly?

Comment: You have two models for handling this, push and pull. In the push model, the object itself has built in support for this, typically through such things as [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx). In a pull-based model you must continously monitor the object and detect the change from the outside. Please clarify if the object has support for such things or if you need to sit on the outside of it. Are you passing the object through an interface reference or as a reference to the class?

Comment: This is some very helpful information, as a relatively new .NET programmer I did not know of some of these things. And @RQDQ I'd like to "perform some action" inside of my concrete class.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I'm not quite sure I understand your question. To clarify, the object which is passed implements an interface, and the class that receives the object only knows about the object's interface. The concrete code that accepts the message is also sitting behind an interface of its own. That's what I was saying in the question. I may have included a little too much information about the architecture of the objects for this question.

Comment: If you can change the object, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, if you cannot, implement a wrapper that implements the same interface and just delegates down to the underlying object, intercepting changes to certain properties, this latter way will only handle external changes, not internal ones. For that you either need to change the object or use the pull-based method.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I can change the object in my particular case, but that's good advice. I'm pretty sure I understand what I need to do, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement INotifyPropertyChanged, also inherit your interface after INotifyPropertyChanged. Then introduce properties for all state ralated things and always in setter methods fire PropertyChanged event.

This requires some boilerplate code but it is very reliable solution. You can make your properties virtual and use IoC containers such as Unity to implement boilerplate for you.

After the implementation is done you simply subscribe to PropertyChanged event of object by using += operator.

```
  myWatchedObject.ProperyChanged += listener.DependentObjectChangeHandler;
```

Comment: To address  your first point, the object that I am paying attention to, does already have it's members implemented as properties. So, firing a `PropertyChanged` event inside of the `set` should be no big deal.

Comment: I guess I could subscribe to that from within my concrete (when the object gets passed in), and handle the event within the concrete.

Comment: To get around the boilerplate try https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: @SirRufo That's pretty sweet, but don't know if I want to take a dependency on that entire library just for that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Encapsulate state of an object using a setter property.
2. Add more code to the setter property to raise an event or call a method.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be properties:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int _MyInteger;
    public int MyInteger 
    { 
        get { return _MyInteger; } 
        set { _MyInteger = value; /* insert your "do some work" code here */ } 
    }
}
```